# Get timestamp of video file captured by OpenCV, Python

Tags: python, opencv, timestamp, video-capture

I am writing a code for following tasks:
1) Capture a video file including human face
2) Detect face
3) Crop the face, and save it as a new video file (only face)

And the program includes a GUI which works as follows:
A) When the user clicks "Record" button, face detection starts (it should save this timestamp as `start_time`)
B) When the user clicks "Stop" button, face detection ends (it should save this timestamp as end_time)

Another output of the program is saving or printing the `start_time` and `end_time`.

I know how to create GUI and my question is not about it. I have a problem to get the `start_time` and `end_time`.

Following is the main part of the code excluding the GUI part:

```
import cv2

video_filename = 'Sample.wmv'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_filename)
print('length = ', cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), '\n')
print('fps = ', cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), '\n')

cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

ResultPath = 'output.wmv'

frame_size = (200, 200)   # Final frame size to save video file

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(ResultPath, fourcc, fps = 25.0, frameSize = frame_size)

start = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret==True:

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Detect faces in the image
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=5,
                minSize=(30, 30),
                )

        # Crop face
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            face_frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            face_frame = cv2.resize(face_frame, frame_size)

            # write the face_frame
            out.write(face_frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        print('Video capture finished')
        end = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print('Start time : ', start, '\n')
print('End time : ', end, '\n')
```

The input video file 'Sample.wmv' has the length of 12 sec, and the frame rate of 15 frames per second. I mean to capture the whole 12 sec of 'Sample.wmv' to test the code.

And followings are the results:

```
length =  12356.0 

fps =  1000.0 

The video capture finished

Start_time :  1.0 

End_time :  360.0
```

As it can be seen, fps is printed as 1000.0 while the frame rate of the input video file is 15. Also, the `end_time` is 360 ms. However, the total duration of the input movie is 12 sec.

Please let me know your idea about the paradoxical results!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Works absolutely as expected on my system, with my video. I used a video of 13 seconds and my end time was 13166 ( 1sec = 1000msec) and start time was 0. Only commented the face detection code.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code with me? Thanks.

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look

Comment: did you try it with another video ?

Comment: Yes, I checked with Avi video files.